# AVSpeechSynthesizer not working on Mac catalyst app

Tags: objective-c, mac-catalyst, avspeechsynthesizer

I have following code to utter a simple text. On iOS the code works well and the text is uttered. But on Mac app it doesn't utter.

```
//Setting up text to speech
synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
synthesizer.delegate = self;

if (synthesizer) {
    if ([synthesizer isSpeaking]) {
        [synthesizer stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];;
    }
}

AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:text];
[utterance setRate:0.5f];
utterance.postUtteranceDelay = 0;
//utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithIdentifier:AVSpeechSynthesisVoiceIdentifierAlex];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self->synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
});
```

On iOS following delegate method is triggered

```
-(void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didFinishSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance{
}
```

but on Mac app it goes straight to didCancelSpeechUtterance

```
-(void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didCancelSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance{
      
}
```

And I don't know how to find the error causing the problem. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed after indicating the language

```
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en"];
```

in iOS it works fine without indicating the language. But on Mac catalyst I guess it is required.